# Unable to patch DefaultExternalUserBuilder in Sitecore 10.1.2

Tags: federated-authentication, coveo, patch-configuration

Our team is using Sitecore 10.1.2 with local environment hosted on developer machines, and deployed environments with K8s and Docker with Coveo serving all of those environments. Only in our deployed environments we are using federated authentication with Azure Active Directory but still using Sitecore's `DefaultExternalUserBuilder`. Attached is our showconfig.aspx, after I am attempting to patch the `externalUserBuilder` to use my assembly that I've created. As you can see, my patch is not showing up in the `externalUserBuilder` section and still shows that is using Sitecore's default.  If I am reading this correctly, it appears that Coveo is being patched in using the default Sitecore user builder.
My patch config is also attached.
From what I understand is that the Coveo config is patched in by http request which may be configured to use the Sitecore default builder. If that is a correct assumption. Would anyone know how to get around that to use my `CustomExternalUserBuilder`?

[image: Patch for Custom Builder]

[image: ShowConfig.aspx]

Comment: Rename, move your config so it is patched after the Coveo one.

Comment: Would be great to see how that config node is seen in showconfig.aspx and I agree with @MarkGibbons comment

Comment: So, I've renamed the file to append ZZZ to the beginning and still no change. I've tripled checked the namespace of the cs file and the reference to it in the patch config. I've also went to the Coveo control panel within the Sitecore CM instance and it shows a list of Coveo config files that are being applied. I feel like I am moving in the wrong direction as it seems odd that Sitecore builds an extensible product that can't be extended if using Coveo. Ill see if I can get that config from the showconfig.aspx and post it

Comment: No information of how the `Coveo.Authentication.config` is being applied. It is only showing 3 other references that it is patching. Similar to the image I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore applies config in the order defined in layers.config.

The default order is:

- sitecore (i.e. `App_Config/Sitecore`)
- modules (i.e. `App_Config/Modules`)
- custom (i.e. `App_Config/Includes`)
- environment (i.e. `App_Config/Environment`)

Based on the comments above, it sounds like you have tried manipulating the naming of your config file to be applied last (alphabetically) in the custom area.

If you have done this correctly and it has had no effect and layers.conig has not been customised. Then the only other possibility is that environment based configuration is overriding your attempts to patch the `DefaultExternalUserBuilder`.

Please check the `App_Config/Environment` folder to see if the Coveo file is present. If so and it need to remain, then you should be able to over ride by placing your file in the environment specific folder (ensuring its name begins later in alphabet - I.e. Z.yourfile.config).

Further information on configuration layers:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/configuration-layers.html

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your config patch is applied after the Coveo config patch. You can create a folder with the name "ZZZ" move your config patch file inside this so that your config patch files will be applied at the end as per the alphabetical order.

Thanks